# Moving from one Modal area to another in Gnome Dialogs

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, mouse, 19.10

My question is about modal menus in gnome. I have launched the "Settings" menu and scrolled down using arrow keys to "Mouse and Touchpad", then pressed Tab and I can see very faint highlighting around selected app topic, for example "Mouse Speed".

However, I can see no way to adjust the Mouse Speed with keyboard alone, it appears "off/on" sliders are responsive to Enter and Space, but "variable sliders" seem to have no keyboard equivalent? Also, can't find a key combo that lets me move in the left pane, e.g., from Printers to Removable Media, once focus is on the right side.

My background in Linux is with FreeBSD a millennium back, when a keyboard was the only control you had. Now trying my hand with Ubuntu 19.10, muddling through with Windows Key equivalents which seem to work about 20-50% of the time in Gnome.

And yes, I've reviewed "Keyboard Shortcuts", right above "Mouse and Touchpad" in the Settings menu, but maybe I'm getting tripped up by the vocabulary.

TIA,
Alex

Comment: GUI with keyboard only was my use case, as I had no mouse and the touchpad had been disabled when a mouse was present. Also I'm old school as I mentioned, and feel there should be a keyboard way for everything!!

Comment: Thanks, Pratap, for the response(s). I found slider wasn't controllable with ARROWS unfortunately.

Comment: 0k I shall try this now as it is clear that you want to achieve the goal with keyboard only..

Comment: The link does indeed point out my concerns regarding the default theme making it hard for old eyes to see highlighted areas. The default theme could be a bit more "high contrast" IMO.

Comment: Indeed, I also do not find a way to move the slider with the keyboard. Alt+Left moves you to a previous panel (if any). To move to the left pane, make sure you first make it back into the header bar (Shift+Tab, ... many many times) and then in the arrow to the left. Flaky keyboard support, to say the least.

Comment: Looks like Alt-Left (political meaning in my country :) will replace the Shift-Tab many many times. Once again IMO only, it would be a strong request to the Gnome UI team to check that all keyboard shortcuts use a "mirror" approach: if Alt-Left does one thing, Alt-Right does the inverse or opposite.